# Django storages azurebackend CMS not displaying media files

Tags: django, azure-blob-storage, django-cms, django-storage

I'm using the storages and django-cms apps with the azure-storage backend in my Django site.  The storage is working great, as when I upload files they are uploaded to my blob container perfectly.  I can confirm that the files are there and publicly accessible.  The problem lies in django-cms display of the images.  The img src is blank and the images are not displayed at all.  I've changed both MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL to my blob storage location but still nothing.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have also added CMS_MEDIA_ROOT, CMS_MEDIA_URL  all set to : "http://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/" nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

How are you confirming that the files are there and publicly accessible? Are you confirming through the management portal?

I don't know much about Django but I skimmed over this page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/files/. From what I understand, MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL are used for locally stored files. I'm not sure if an Azure Storage endpoint can be used here but again I'm not familiar with Django.